# Calculating a summary of tuples' length not including aliasing in python

Tags: python, tuples, pointer-aliasing

Given the following code, I've been asked to calculate how many different tuples (aliasing tuples are to be excluded) are in the returned tuple of the function:

```
def tuple_maker(k):
    result = tuple()
    length = len(result)
    for i in range(k):
        result = (i,result * i)
        length += len(result)
    print(length)
    return result

res = tuple_maker(4)
```

This is the value of `res` variable:

> (3, (2, (1, (0, ()), 1, (0, ())), 2, (1, (0, ()), 1, (0, ())), 2, (1, (0, ()), 1, (0, ()))))

The given answer is 5 different tuples of which I was correct, but the second question was to calculate the total length of the tuple in `res` variable. The code above prints `8`, while the answer is `14`.

What do I miss here?

Comment: adjust your lenght calculation inside the for loop to:
 length += len(result)+i

Comment: Care to elaborate why ?

Comment: actually i am not sure from where you get the value 14? Do you have further examples/results. For example for tuple_maker(5) ?

Comment: Sadly, I only have the numeric answer for the question with '4' as input.
I see that adding 'i' to calculation will fix the problem but I can't seem to understand the why

Comment: mightve been just a coincidence. unfortunatly i cannot comprehend why the result has to be 14. because when i count all the inputs in your output it equals to 23 :)
If you can give me a further explanation why the result has to be 14 then i can dig into it. otherwise further help wont be possible